# Is there a better way to add a new playlist to iTunes through Javascript for Automation (JXA)?

Tags: javascript, applescript, itunes, javascript-automation

There must be a better way to create a new element in a collection (if that's what really happens behind the abstraction).

I'm looking for the JXA equivalent of this applescript

```
if (count of (playlists whose name is plName)) is 0 then
  make new playlist with properties { name: plName }
end if
```

I have tried a number of things, but can't get an equivalent. The closest I can get is to duplicate an existing playlist and then rename it...

```
if ( iTunes.userPlaylists.whose( { name: {_equals: plName } } ).length == 0 ) {
    mnp = iTunes.userPlaylists[0].duplicate()
    mnp.name.set( plName )
}
```

Any hints on the cleanest way to test for a playlist's existence, or to select a playlist to duplicate are welcome. Like most people, due to the appalling lack of documentation for JXA, I'm figuring most of the application interaction stuff out by experimentation.

My *main question* though is whether there is a way to create an empty playlist without having to duplicate one. Not that it matters I guess if I have a work around, but it just feels like a kludge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about the simplest way:

```
mnp = iTunes.UserPlaylist().make()
mnp.name = plName
```

Have fun, Michael / Hamburg

Comment: Ugh! Thank you. I tried so many variations, but obviously not this one - though I thought I had. I suspect I might have accidentally used the plural (`mnp = iTunes.UserPlaylists().make()`) so close!